# Getting 500 undocumented error as "Connection prematurely closed DURING response" after executing rest api for file upload

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, httpresponse

Created a rest api in Springboot application which takes file through POST rest api and do some processing and returns some response.
but when executed that post api it shows an error below as..

**Connection prematurely closed during response**

Code snippet for the restcontroller is as follows.

```
@CrossOrigin(origins="*")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class Script{

@Autowired 
ScriptService sevice;

private static final Logger logger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(LensMigration.class);

@PostMapping("/api/v1/execute/script")
public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Integer>> executeScript(@RequestParam(value = "file") MultipartFile file)
            throws IOException {

logger.info("inside endpoint!!!");

        if (file.isEmpty()) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("file doen not exists!!");
        } else {
            BufferedReader csvReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file.getInputStream()));
            return new ResponseEntity<>(service.migrateOldRecords(csvReader), HttpStatus.OK);

        }
    }



}
```

I have used some loggers at start of controller to check if it is executing, but didn't get any logs printed.

May be error due to response time
so I have tried to increase the response time using servlet property but it didn't worked

```
server.connection-timeout=60000
```

could anyone help me here please.

Comment: Add code as text not as Image. Also see the server log for more Information.

Comment: sure @Jens .but could you suggest some possible causes

Comment: Not without any error message.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is very strange to me that it gets solved by just adding the @RequestMapping annotation to different path.

The root cause of the issue was the endpoint inside controller was not visible. The actual error I was expecting is that 404 not found for this particular POST api.

I did get 404 not found error for another GET endpoint which I just written below this POST api.

So due to this 404 I was looking for visibility of the endpoint
and its gets resolved.